# Why I can't use variable for program name in start command?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script that eventually starts another batch file and waits for it to complete. Here is the syntax I originally had:

```
for %%i in ("*.xml") do start /separate /wait "%PROGRAM_PATH%" "%LOCAL_OUTGOING_PATH%\%%i"
```

What happened is that instead of opening the program that %PROGRAM_PATH% points to, it ended up launching Internet Explorer and showing the XML file specified by %%i. It was like as though it ignored the %PROGRAM_PATH% portion of the start command. I tried using %PROGRAM_NAME% without quotes that didn't work either. %PROGRAM_PATH%, by the way, points to "
"C:\DOS\copy.bat". So I ended up having to hard code the path in there like this:

```
for %%i in ("*.xml") do start /separate /wait C:\DOS\copy.bat "%LOCAL_OUTGOING_PATH%\%%i"
```

This made it finally work the way I wanted it to. But I want to be able to use a variable. Why doesn't that work?

Comment: You say you used `%PROGRAM_NAME%` without quotes.  Did you mean `%PROGRAM_PATH%`?  If not, then what's the value of `PROGRAM_NAME`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I checked to make sure the variable names matched up too.

Comment: I tried this (on Win XP) and it works for me without the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first START parameter enclosed in quotes is taken as the Window Title. If you want to give a parameter enclosed in quotes you MUST first provide a title, even an empty one:

```
for %%i in ("*.xml") do start "" /separate /wait "%PROGRAM_PATH%" "%LOCAL_OUTGOING_PATH%\%%i"
```

or

```
for %%i in ("*.xml") do start "Win Title" /separate /wait "%PROGRAM_PATH%" "%LOCAL_OUTGOING_PATH%\%%i"
```

Type START /? for further details.